# Firebase blank html page when deployed , but works on local host

Tags: html, firebase, local, host

I am currently developing a firbase app. I am having an issue where whenever I run my firbaseapp on local machine it works perfectly but when deployed to firebase server I get a blank screen. Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Look for errors in the JS console. Check to make sure you are using case-sensitive filenames (Firebase Hosting is case-sensitive, Mac OS / Windows are not).